# max() without arithmetics or so

Tags: pascal

I have a plan to make something to solve this stuff:

You have 7   chips that are on the run. each has some cargo loaded. And also there's `where` record on each.Latter could be either `track` means running(or gone offroad)  or `tobeauty` means it reaches its finish. Where `.cargo = -1` means it's gone . And finally i need one of three : all is gone, at least one is on finish and others either are on finish or gone , and show is in progress so neither of these two. Only first two will be checked so thrd will be just anything else.

I've done it like this finally:

```pascal
uses crt;

type 
    trail_type = (blue ,desert ,white ,green ,violet ,wood ,coldgreen) ;
    palmtree = (none ,apple ,appricot ,grape ,pineapple ,lemon);
    catchinon  = (track, tobeauty);
type
    ontherun = Record
    trail : trail_type;
    cargo : Currency;
    miles : Integer;
    where : catchinon;
end;

Var 
    rec_b : array[1..7] of ontherun;
    fruit : palmtree;
    k  : Integer;

Function Ternary(x : Boolean ; b : palmtree ; c  : palmtree ) : palmtree;
begin
    if x then
        Ternary := b
    else
        Ternary := c;
end;
begin
    {testing part}

{       rec_b[4].cargo := -1;
        rec_b[5].where := tobeauty;
        rec_b[7].where := tobeauty;
        rec_b[1].cargo := -1;
        rec_b[3].where := tobeauty;
        fruit := none;}

    {for k := 1 to 7 do
                        rec_b[k].where := tobeauty;}
    for k := 1 to 7 do
        rec_b[k].cargo := -1;
    rec_b[7].where := tobeauty;
    rec_b[7].cargo := 20;

    {testing part ended}

    fruit := none;

    for k := 1 to 7 do
    begin
        fruit := Ternary((rec_b[k].where = tobeauty) and ( fruit in [none , pineapple]), appricot , fruit );
        fruit := Ternary((rec_b[k].cargo = -1) and ( not (fruit in  [grape])), lemon ,  fruit); 
        fruit := Ternary((rec_b[k].where = track) and ( fruit in [ none , appricot , apple , pineapple]), grape , fruit);
        fruit := Ternary((rec_b[k].cargo = -1) and ( fruit  in  [lemon ]), pineapple ,  fruit); 
        fruit := Ternary((rec_b[k].where = tobeauty) and ( fruit in [pineapple, appricot]), apple , fruit );
    end;
    Writeln(fruit); 
end.
```

Are there some tricks on that do you know?

Comment: Depending on your definition of _arithmetics_ `max() without arithmetics` could be achieved by `card([1..X, 1..Y, 1..Z])` for non-negative values in Extended Pascal.